# How to make <span> text wrap nicely below start of first line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a simple

```
label: value
```

pairing look nice. The problem I have is that when the value is so long that it wraps around and goes on to a second line, the second line starts below the label text. I would like it to start on the same horizontal position as the first line of text.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="status-container">

  <span class="status-label">Status:</span>

  <span class="status-text">This is some rather long text that I would like to the second line of text to start at the same horizontal position as the first line. At the moment it wraps beneath the 'status:' label which is annoying</span>

</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.status-container {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.status-text {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

I have create a PLNKR to show how it looks: https://plnkr.co/edit/qbFj4bwEpPf7aUldvjBU

I am sure I am forgetting something extremely simple and obvious, but it is a while since I did this CSS stuff..... All help much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And don't forget the `overflow:hidden` trick:

```css
.status-label {
  float:left; padding-right:10px;
}
.status-text {
  overflow:hidden; display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="status-container">
  <span class="status-label">Status:</span>
  <span class="status-text">This is some rather long text that I would like to the second line of text to start at the same horizontal position as the first line. At the moment it wraps beneath the 'status:' label which is annoying</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably one of the best/quickest ways with the best browser support is to use [`display:table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display):

```css
.status-container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: table;
}
.status-text {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.status-label {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="status-container">

  <span class="status-label">Status:</span>

  <span class="status-text">This is some rather long text that I would like to the second line of text to start at the same horizontal position as the first line. At the moment it wraps beneath the 'status:' label which is annoying</span>

</div>
```

Otherwise, if you don't need IE9 support, use a [flexbox layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
.status-container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
}
.status-text {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="status-container">

  <span class="status-label">Status:</span>

  <span class="status-text">This is some rather long text that I would like to the second line of text to start at the same horizontal position as the first line. At the moment it wraps beneath the 'status:' label which is annoying</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always display them table-like

```
.status-label{
 display:table-cell;
}
.status-text{
 display: table-cell;
 padding-left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use inline block in your css classes to make them line up horizontally.

```
.status-label, .status-text {
    display: inline-block;
}
```