# Move text inside the same <p> when a class is already applied?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to re-format an EPUB using the PDF format of the same book as a model using Calibre. I found this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGPWt.jpg

I want to: Make the text on the right look the same as the one on the left.

The EPUB is like this:

Code:

```css
.calibre {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin: 0 5pt;
}

.p2 {
  text-indent: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="" xml:lang="">

<body class="calibre">

  <p class="p2">It was hard to not watch his Status Page like a hawk (which apparently lived in the mountain areas), but he watched  his  level  slowly  rise  over  the  course  of   the cycle. </p>
  
  <p class="p2">Level 19.02  –  A Red Wolf.</p>

  <p class="p2">Level 19.08  –  Three more Red Wolves.</p>

  <p class="p2">Level 19.13  –  Some Psycho Killer Bees guarding a Blue Chest with a  <i class="calibre3">Pretty Rock</i> in it.</p> 

  <p class="p2">Level 19.22  –  An  Undead  Swordsman  and  his Skelemaidens. </p>

  <p class="p2">Level 19.29  –  A pack of  Fish Otters. </p>

  <p class="p2">Level 19.38  –  A very angry-looking Stump. </p>

  <p class="p2">Level 19.45  –  Three more Red Wolves. </p>

  <p class="p2">Level 19.57  –  Some Psycho Killer Bees guarding a Blue Chest with a  <i class="calibre3">Pretty Rock</i> in it. (He had gotten turned around at some point and had ended up going in a circle.)</p>

  <p class="p2">Level 19.66   –  A trip back to kill some Heat Pigs in the Salazarm Desert for more <i>Desert Bacon. </i></p>
  
  </body>

</html>
```

I just want to change the part after the " - ". On the PDF, it doesn't continue under 'level 19.XX'. If I try to change the text-align using span or something similar it doesn't work. I don't know what to do anymore.

I hope I managed to explain it well. Any ideas?

EDIT: I'll expand the code to what it looks like:

Comment: Looks like it can be a table (3 column table)

Comment: I tried a table already since I had to add one to another chapter. Maybe it's my fault, but I'm not able to make it look right. That's what I tried just before posting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to follow this html structure to get this...

I wrapped line with div status-container and then divide label and text separately

I find this solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40267177/how-to-make-span-text-wrap-nicely-below-start-of-first-line?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```css
.status-label {
  float:left; padding-right:5px;
}
.status-text {
  overflow:hidden; display:block;
}
.p2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="" xml:lang="">
       <body class="calibre">
          <p class="p2">It was hard to not watch his Status Page like a hawk (which apparently lived in the mountain areas), but he watched  his  level  slowly  rise  over  the  course  of   the cycle. </p>
          <div class="status-container">
             <p class="p2"><span class="status-label">Level 19.02  –  </span><span class="status-text">A Red Wolf.</span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="status-container">
             <p class="p2"><span class="status-label">Level 19.08  – </span> <span class="status-text">Three more Red Wolves.</span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="status-container">
             <p class="p2"><span class="status-label">Level 19.13  – </span> <span class="status-text">Some Psycho Killer Bees guarding a Blue Chest with a  <i class="calibre3">Pretty Rock</i> in it.</span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="status-container">
             <p class="p2"><span class="status-label">Level 19.22  – </span><span class="status-text"> An  Undead  Swordsman  and  his Skelemaidens. </span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="status-container">
             <p class="p2"><span class="status-label">Level 19.29  – </span><span class="status-text"> A pack of  Fish Otters. </span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="status-container">
             <p class="p2"><span class="status-label">Level 19.38  – </span><span class="status-text"> A very angry-looking Stump. </span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="status-container">
             <p class="p2"><span class="status-label">Level 19.45  –  </span><span class="status-text">Three more Red Wolves. </span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="status-container">
             <p class="p2"><span class="status-label">Level 19.57  – </span> <span class="status-text">Some Psycho Killer Bees guarding a Blue Chest with a  <i class="calibre3">Pretty Rock</i> in it. (He had gotten turned around at some point and had ended up going in a circle.)</span></p>
          </div>
          <div class="status-container">
             <p class="p2"><span class="status-label">Level 19.66   – </span> <span class="status-text">A trip back to kill some Heat Pigs in the Salazarm Desert for more <i>Desert Bacon. </i></span></p>
          </div>
       </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked fine with just a giant div. And had to change my p class for one without text-indent as you later edited. I added a padding-left of 1.5em to make it look like it had indent and so far it looks amazing :) Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help you :)